# Android background service app

Tags: android, android-service

I want to create an android app that runs on the background, there should not be any UI or Launcher, app should runs on the startup, Is there any example I could follow, I found few resource but those are not helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

First of all look at the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) of Services, see for yourself if this is really what you need. Then for your second part of question, you can ask the system to tell you about the device booting completed and run the service. You can find more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I went through these questions and documentation. there are lot of example but not working. I want to do this without using a UI